# Blogger Template: How is inline style tag getting attached to img?

Tags: css, blogger, templates, xml, tags

\\\\ Correction discovered it's a Javascript feature, thanks.

Examining a blogger template's img tag (data:post.thumbnailUrl) i've approached a mystery.

An inline style tag controlling the width, margin and heigh perimeters are getting added to my img element.

They are auto adjusting the images ratio to fit a smaller size.

But I can't figure-out where this style tag script lives and how it's happening 
in my template. My template has no special javascript or jquery scripts.

The full size images in the single posts page don't have this style tag.

Is this a css or xml feature?

```
element.style {
margin-top: 0px;
width: 301.0033444816054px;
height: 200px;
margin-left: -0.5016722408026908px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you post the link to blogger, we can look at the scripts and try to find the culprit.

Comment: It might be difficult to locate, but after disabling the browsers Javascript I found it's somewhere in there. url: hollywoodgosssip.com/eFQ  - Recent thumbnails.

Comment: Found a similar working script but still not the same. http://ericjuden.com/2009/07/jquery-image-resize/